# Can't access REST service with valid keycloak token after secure with keycloak

Tags: java, rest, token, keycloak

using keycloak Java API to get a valid token then using this token to try to access a rest service that has been secured with keycloak but get 404 error, Not Found.

It seems the token is not working?

Here is my java code to get the token from keycloak. This appears to work:

```
AuthzClient authzClient = AuthzClient.create();
AccessTokenResponse response = authzClient.obtainAccessToken(user, password);
```

I get a valid token in the response. I then try to use this token to access the REST service secured with keycloak:

```
    String urlString = "http://localhost:3333/appname-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/project/0.1/device/return/all";

    URL url = new URL(urlString); 
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    String authString = "Bearer " + tokenStr;
    con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authString);
    basicStatus = con.getResponseCode();
```

The basicStatus returns 404

I secured the war file with the REST service by adding a web.xml file and a keycloak.json file. If I remove the web.xml and keycloak.json file from the war, then above code returns 200. But then the service is not secure.

web.xml:

```
<module-name>application</module-name>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Device</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/device/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>device</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>KEYCLOAK</auth-method>
    <realm-name>this is ignored currently</realm-name>
</login-config>

<security-role>
    <role-name>device</role-name>
</security-role>
```

user has role of device in keycloak.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say before anything, please remove "http://" from your "http://localhost:3333/......." resource server root location URL and retry. If that doesn't solve your problem I'd recommend using something like postman where you can test/prototype much faster.

1 - use this endponit for getting your tokens (send as x-www-form-urlencoded): HOST:PORT/auth/realms/YOUR_REALM/protocol/openid-connect/token

2 parameters are: grant_type (value: password), client_id, usernmae, & password (if your client's access type is "confidential" or "bearer-only" you'll need to privide a client_secret also)

3  after this work, just check that in your java client you are using same values.

Hope it helps.

**EDIT: ok this is 11 months old XD.... nevermind**